# How to create a datatable with arbitrary columns and data?

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient, angular-datatables

I have an application where an user can make a selection in a dropdown which triggers a request and the output - in this case a table - is shown on the website. The data always comes in `JSON` format like this:

```
'{"columns":["C1","C2"], "data":[[8,98],[22,95],[43,29],[79,29]]}';
'{"columns":["foo","bar","xyz"], "data":[[27,26,3],[54,80,93],[92,10,90]]}';
```

In the `jQuery` world, I could then always do something like this:

```
table = $("#a_nice_table").DataTable({
              data: response.data,
              columns: response.columns
            });
```

and the table shows in the `div` called `a_nice_table`.

I would now like to do the same in Angular, but struggle with the population of the website.

I have a component `dt-dropdown.component` like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dt-dropdown',
  templateUrl: './dt-dropdown.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dt-dropdown.component.css']
})
export class DtDropdownComponent implements OnInit {

  ddSelector: string = "";
  response: any;
  tableJSON1: string = '{"columns":["C1","C2"], "data":[[8,98],[22,95],[43,29],[79,29]]}';
  tableJSON2: string = '{"columns":["foo","bar","xyz"], "data":[[27,26,3],[54,80,93],[92,10,90]]}';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() { }

  getTable() {
    this.http.get('https://api.github.com/users/alan-agius4') // + this.ddSelector
    .subscribe((response) => {

      // usually without the if-clause
      if (this.ddSelector === 'type1') {
        this.response = JSON.parse(this.tableJSON1);
      } else {
        this.response = JSON.parse(this.tableJSON2);
      }
      // this.response = response;
      console.log(response);
      console.log(JSON.parse(this.tableJSON1));
    });
  }
}
```

The `if` clause is now just for demonstration purposes; usually this is not needed and the `response` would  be directly passed.

The corresponding `HTML` looks like this:

```
Choose something: 
<select [(ngModel)]="ddSelector">
    <option>type1</option>
    <option>type2</option>
</select>
<button (click)="getTable()">Get table!</button>
<div *ngIf="response">
    <table datatable class="row-border hover">
        <thead>
            {{ response.columns }}
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {{ response.data}}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

That, however, always results in

> ERROR TypeError: "aoColumns[srcCol] is undefined"

How would I do this correctly?

I guess I cannot not just use `{{ response.columns }}` and `{{ response.data}}` but somehow need to loop, but not sure.

Comment: There's no mention of `aoColumns[srcCol]` in your code?

Comment: @user184994: Yes, I think that comes from `angular-datatables`. I found [this link](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/13872/a-aocolumns-c-is-undefined) but not sure how to use the information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to display data in `HTML file` this way:

```
<table datatable class="row-border hover">
    <thead>
       <tr>
        <th *ngFor="let column of response.columns">
          {{ column }}
        </th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     <tr *ngFor="let row of response.data">
       <td *ngFor="let cell of row">{{cell}}</td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: That almost works. For the first time, the table is shown correctly, when I switch the type and push the button the second time, the header is not shown but only the data. Any ideas?

Comment: Seems it does not like that there is a different number of columns; when I return the same table in both cases, it works fine.

Comment: @Cleb Try setting `response = null` in the very first line of `getTable()`. That will force the table to reload each time the data is fetched

Comment: @user184994: That does the trick, thanks! Do you think these nested loops are the best way of doing it? For these small tables it is quite fast, but I am wondering whether one runs into performance issues for bigger ones...

Comment: @Cleb, Somewhere down the line it's going to need to do some nested loops if you want dynamic tables

Comment: @user184994: Ok. Was just wondering as for `jQuery` I could just pass arrays, but no idea what it does under the hood later on... Thanks for you help!

Comment: @Cleb, if u know you will have a lot of data, you can make rows as separated components, which will lazy load data, when component gets rendered it has few lifecycle hooks eg. `OnViewInit`, where you can call for another piece of data by http request and fill cells in row component as data arrivces

Comment: @Jake11: That sounds great! Would it be a lot of work to add this to the answer? If so, could you point me to any resource where this is used? I started with Angular only two days ago, so I have not much knowledge on this topic, unfortunately...

Comment: @Cleb, https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks, https://scotch.io/tutorials/3-ways-to-pass-async-data-to-angular-2-child-components